# How do I remove duplicate code in the query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

this query use of **distinct**.
**But duplicate codes have been not removed.**
In fact, the main reason duplicated  code, is comments.
Duplicated code in the query below in the section **UserTimeLineComments** occurs.

```
    var UserTimeLineNews = (from l in _newsService.NewsQuery()
                            where l.UserId == UserId && l.IsActive == true
                            orderby l.CreateDate descending
                            select new UserTimeLine
                            {
                                EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                TimeLineType = TimeLineType.CreateNews,
                                Title = l.Title,
                                Abstract = l.NewsAbstract,
                                CommentContent =null,
                                CommentCount = l.CommentCount,
                                LikeCount = l.LikeCount,
                                ViewsCount = l.ViewsCount,
                                Storyteller = l.Storyteller
                            }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

    var UserTimeLineLikeNews = (from l in _likeNewsService.LikeNewsQueryable()
                                where l.UserId == UserId
                                orderby l.CreateDate descending
                                select new UserTimeLine
                                {
                                    EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                    TimeLineType = TimeLineType.LikeNews,
                                    Title = l.News.Title,
                                    Abstract = l.News.NewsAbstract,
                                    CommentContent =null,
                                    CommentCount = l.News.CommentCount,
                                    LikeCount = l.News.LikeCount,
                                    ViewsCount = l.News.ViewsCount,
                                    Storyteller = l.News.Storyteller
                                }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

    var UserTimeLineComments = (from l in _commentService.CommentQueryable()
                                where l.UserId == UserId && l.IsActive == true
                                orderby l.CreateDate descending
                                select new UserTimeLine
                                {
                                    EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                    TimeLineType = TimeLineType.Comment,
                                    Title = l.News.Title,
                                    Abstract = l.News.NewsAbstract,
                                    CommentContent = l.Content,
                                    CommentCount = l.News.CommentCount,
                                    LikeCount = l.News.LikeCount,
                                    ViewsCount = l.News.ViewsCount,
                                    Storyteller = l.News.Storyteller
                                }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

    var item = (UserTimeLineNews
        .Union(UserTimeLineLikeNews)
        .Union(UserTimeLineComments))
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.EventDate)
        .Distinct()
        .Take(NumberOfNews)
        .ToList();
```

I use 'implement IEquatable with UserTimeLine class' but error message appears.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[UserTimeLine] Distinct[UserTimeLine](System.Linq.IQueryable1[UserTimeLine], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[UserTimeLine])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
 public class DistinctNews : IEqualityComparer<UserTimeLine>
 {
    public bool Equals(UserTimeLine x, UserTimeLine y)
    {
        return x.NewsId==y.NewsId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(UserTimeLine obj)
    {
        return obj.NewsId.GetHashCode();
    }
  }

 var item = (UserTimeLineNews
        .Union(UserTimeLineLikeNews)
        .Union(UserTimeLineComments))
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.EventDate)
        .Distinct(new DistinctNews())
        .Take(NumberOfNews)
        .ToList();
```

**I use 'implement IEquatable with UserTimeLine class' but duplicate codes have been not removed**

```
public class UserTimeLine: IEquatable<UserTimeLine>
{
    public long NewsId { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
    //and other property        

    public bool Equals(UserTimeLine other)
    {  
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return NewsId.Equals(other.NewsId) && Title.Equals(other.Title);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {  
        int hashNewsTitel = Title == null ? 0 : Title.GetHashCode();

        int hashNewsId = NewsId.GetHashCode();

        return hashNewsTitel ^ hashNewsId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `group by` but not on all fields.

Comment: How to use group by this query?

Comment: I don't know the goal of this query, but as it contains counts I think you'd want to group by all fields except the counts and then `Sum` the counts.

Comment: I don't understand if you want to remove something from the query result of from the code itself. Could you explain?

Comment: I want to remove duplicate code. 
Code duplication problem was solved with the help of friends. Now the problem is that the query output IList type, the result is correct. (This method is not optimal), but when I choose IQueryable query output type, an error message appears.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ's `Distinct()` method uses the default equality comparer, which - for reference types like your `UserTimeLine` class, checks for reference equality. As you create different object in your queries, these all are distinct.

You need to

a) either implement `IEquatable<T>` with your `UserTimeLine` class

```
class UserTimeLine: IEquatable<UserTimeLine>
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    /* other properties omitted for brevity */

    public bool Equals(UserTimeLine other) {
        return this.NewsId == other.NewsId;
    }
}
```

b) or use the Distinct overload, that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that does the comparison

Comment: I do not understand!
Please do a little more guidance.

Comment: If you implement this interface it's implementation overrides the default comparison. From now on, whenever two instances of `UserTimeLine` are compared for equality (like `Distinct()` does), it will call the `Equals` method, which compares the `NewsId` of both instances. As I understood your question, this is the behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I use 'implement IEquatable with UserTimeLine class' but duplicate codes have been not removed.

Comment: The problem is, queries of type IQueryable output and final output type is IList.
If the output of the queries to select the type IList problem will be solved, but I do not want to change the output of the queries!